# AMP analytics form -submission tracking

Tags: google-analytics, amp-html

Hi everyone I am trying to track a form on an AMP website.
I have already tried to track the visibility of the success message via GTM
and is not working
apparently form the documentation the event tracking on AMP is done by this

```
    <amp-analytics type="gtag" data-credentials="include">
  <script type="application/json">
    {
      "vars": {
        "gtag_id": "<GA_TRACKING_ID>",
        "config": {
         "<GA_TRACKING_ID>": { "groups": "default" }
        }
      },
      "triggers": {
        "button": {
          "selector": "#the-button",
          "on": "click",
          "vars": {
            "event_name": "login",
            "method": "Google"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  </script>
</amp-analytics>
```

I have tried to use it in this way:

```
<amp-analytics type="gtag" data-credentials="include">
  <script type="application/json">
    {
      "vars": {
        "gtag_id": "UA-48872168-2",
        "config": {
         "UA-48872168-2": { "groups": "default" }
        }
      },
      "triggers": {
        "form": {
          "selector": "#contact-form",
          "on": "submit-sucess",
          "vars": {
            "event_name": "CATEGORIA",
            "method": "AZIONE"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  </script>
</amp-analytics>
```

and is not tracking: any ideas?
Thank you in advance