# AMP analytics tracking not sending event

Tags: javascript, html, google-analytics, analytics, amp-html

I'm trying to track a form submission with Google Analytics and AMP and it's not working - I looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53780880/amp-analytics-form-submission-tracking) question but there wasn't an answer, so I was hoping someone might be able to answer it now.

Here's a live example of what I'm trying to do: [makethewebfree.com](https://makethewebfree.com). As you can see in the code below, I tried to set up a trigger using the example I found on the amp website. It's tracking the initial pageview but nothing after that.

Here's my code:

```
<form method="post" action-xhr="..." target="_top">
    <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email..." required><input id="signup" type="submit" value="Sign me up">
    <div submit-success>
        <template type="amp-mustache">
            Success! We'll let you know when we do something
        </template>
    </div>
    <div submit-error>
        <template type="amp-mustache">
            I guess there was an error - can you try again later?
        </template>
    </div>
</form>
```

And here's the AMP portion:

```
<amp-analytics type="googleanalytics">
<script type="application/json">
{
  "vars": {
    "account": "..."
  },
  "triggers": {
    "default pageview": {
      "on": "visible",
      "request": "pageview",
      "vars": {
        "title": "Home Page"
      }
    }
  },
    "click on #signup trigger": {
      "on": "click",
      "selector": "#signup",
      "request": "event",
      "vars": {
        "eventCategory": "subscribe",
        "eventAction": "subscribe-clicked"
      }
    }
}
</script>
</amp-analytics>
```

I'm not getting any amp validation errors, so I'm not sure what the problem could be. I'm thinking maybe the amp form submission is preventing the trigger from being fired.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

(I filled in the parts that have `...` with the actual values, just trying to make a simpler example)

Comment: Note: I also tried the events `submit-success` and `submit-error` and neither of those worked (I used the form element as the selector